# Why is my twitter-api-php not working?

Tags: php, twitter

I'm trying to get the most recent tweets from Twitter with their PHP api.

I first used composer to download the files.

**composer.json**

```
{
    "require": {
        "j7mbo/twitter-api-php": "dev-master"
    }
}
```

This composer install gave me the vendor files, in particular, **TwitterAPIExchange.php**

This is the rest of my code:**Please assume the contents of TwitterAPIExchange.php are correct and that all the tokens and codes are correct.**

```
<?php

    require_once('TwitterAPIExchange.php');

    $settings = array(
        'oauth_access_token' => "#",
        'oauth_access_token_secret' => "#",
        'consumer_key' => "#",
        'consumer_secret' => "#"
    );

    $url = 'https://api.twitter.com/1.1/blocks/create.json';
    $requestMethod = 'POST';

    $postfields = array(
        'screen_name' => 'usernameToBlock',
        'skip_status' => '1'
    );

    $twitter = new TwitterAPIExchange($settings);
    echo $twitter->buildOauth($url, $requestMethod)
        ->setPostfields($postfields)
        ->performRequest();

    ?>
```

I got the above code from [here](https://github.com/J7mbo/twitter-api-php).

I'm getting the following PHP error:

> Fatal error: Uncaught exception 'Exception' with message 'SSL certificate problem: unable to get local issuer certificate' in C:\xampp\htdocs\TwitterAPIExchange.php:315 Stack trace: #0 C:\xampp\htdocs\twitter.php(23): TwitterAPIExchange->performRequest() #1 {main} thrown in C:\xampp\htdocs\TwitterAPIExchange.php on line 315

The console has the following error: `Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 (Not Found)`'

How do I fix this problem?

Comment: @Jay Blandchard I don't think this is a duplicate. I went to the answer and it said to change the contents of a file called `ParseClient.php`. I'm using XAMPP and see no file that exists under that name. Can you redirect me to a solution for XAMPP? :)

Comment: There are several duplicates out there for this error and each of them point to a `curl()` setting.

Comment: yes it's seem's you need add this : curl_setopt($feed, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, false); in after line 305 of justo at the bottom of curl init , TwitterAPIExchange.php , also maybe you will have a look at php.ini to check curl options.

Comment: @JoaquinJavi I did the code you said and got back the error `Catchable fatal error: Argument 2 passed to curl_setopt_array() must be of the type array, integer given, called in C:\xampp\htdocs\twitter.php on line 23 and defined in C:\xampp\htdocs\TwitterAPIExchange.php on line 307`

Comment: i put curl_setopt instead to curl_setopt_array can you post your code